# Redeploying OpenAPI spec into App Engine standard environment

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

When I do some changes in OpenAPI spec, which don't involve any changes in the code, do I need to redeploy the code along with the new specification?

When I deploy OpenAPI spec with `gcloud service-management deploy` command I get back in it's output new service configuration version, which I should set to the `ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_VERSION` parameter in the `app.yaml` file.

I'm not sure but it looks like I have to redeploy the app every time I deploy a new version of my OpenAPI spec, even when the application code doesn't change I still need to point it to the right service configuration version with the new `ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_VERSION` value, is that right?

If so, then it's different from what is described in the [How API Deployment Works](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/deploy-redeploy-api) document for AE flex environment under the "Redeployment" section, where it says the following:

> You can use the gcloud service-management deploy command to update
>   just the API specification without redeploying your backend API server
>   code or the Extensible Service Proxy. This is useful if you are
>   changing a configuration-only detail.
>
> When you change the API specification, the Service Control API backing
>   your running service instances will pick up the change because as it
>   depends on the same service configuration.

Maybe someone could help to clarify how exactly it works in case of AE standard environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the Endpoints Frameworks? If so, then you will have to deploy the app when you make a new service config version, because, as you mentioned, the `app.yaml` specifies which service config to use.

Comment: Yes, I use Endpoints Frameworks in Python. Thanks for the answer! It just feels a bit of an overkill to redeploy full app every time I'm tweaking something in the OpenAPI spec...